# How to use only a few commands from a package?

Tags: macros, packages, siunitx, package-options

I am writing a quantum mechanics lecture note. So I use \ket{} very often. 
I also use siunitx package and the package has a command \kelvin.

The \kelvin command appears above \ket in the overleaf auto-complete, and it is inconvenient as I use \ket far more often than \kelvin.

Is there a way I can use the siunitx package, excluding \kelvin? or a way to import only a few commands from siunitx?

Comment: the overleaf completion and the tex definitions won't be directly related so you can probably alter the completion without changing the tex code (and conversely if you make additional tex definitions that change the package loading that will not necessarily affect the editor completion code) (sorry I can't help with overleaf specifics)

Comment: This has nothing to do with LaTeX. Overleaf knows about some packages and adds completions for the comands they provide; this is independent of what the packages do. If you were able to load `siunitx` without it defining `\kelvin`, Overleaf would show the completion nonetheless.

Comment: The Overleaf command completion suggestions use quite a bit of behind the scenes data analysis, so I doubt they are tweakable at the user level. https://www.overleaf.com/blog/523-a-data-driven-approach-to-latex-autocomplete